# Implementing parent-child relationships in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to Fluent NHibernate. I pay much attention to the "cleanness" of the SQL model it generates.

Currently I have an OpenID-based authentication system where each user can be associated to multiple OpenIDs, and have a personal password. The entities look like the following (simplified to essential):

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<OpenId> OpenIds { get; set; }
    }

public class OpenId
    {
        public virtual Uri Uri { get; set; }

        public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically I want to navigate from the OpenID to the corresponding `Owner` and vice-versa, given a user, fetch his associated `OpenIds`.

The problem is with the generated SQL. The following is the mapping:

```
internal class UserMapping : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress);

        HasMany(x => x.OpenIds)
            .Inverse()
            .AsBag()
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad()
            .NotFound.Ignore()
            .Fetch.Join();


    }
}

internal class OpenIdMapping : ClassMap<OpenId>
{
    public OpenIdMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Uri);

        References(x => x.Owner)
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

The generated SQL of the child entity looks as follows

```
create table `OpenId` (Uri VARCHAR(255) not null, Owner_id BIGINT, User_id BIGINT, primary key (Uri))
alter table `OpenId` add index (Owner_id), add constraint FKA39F7E21DE3E69E4 foreign key (Owner_id) references `User` (Id)
alter table `OpenId` add index (User_id), add constraint FKA39F7E21E052E59D foreign key (User_id) references `User` (Id)
```

I don't want both `Owner_id` and `User_id` columns, as they are redundant

### In general

How does one create a two-way-navigable parent-child relationship in Fluent NHibernate? How does one **avoid** having redundant foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that both sides of the association use the same foreign key column.

```
HasMany(x => x.OpenIds)
        .KeyColumn("Owner_id")
        .Inverse()
        .AsBag()
        .Cascade.All()
        .LazyLoad()
        .NotFound.Ignore()
        .Fetch.Join()
```

The References statement also offers a method to specify a custom column name. So you may use a column name like "Owner" without the id suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring `Owner` property to `User` still works